# Не вызывается метод update, receive виджета, после конфигурационного экрана

Tags: java, android

Почему то не хочет обновляться виджет после вызова конфигурационного экрана. Экран вызывает, но после завершения ничего. Сейчас предоставлю код, помогите, пожалуйста.
manifest.xml:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".widget.CamWidgetProvider"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"></action>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/cam_widget_meta"></meta-data>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".widget.CamWidgetConfig"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

cam_widget_meta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/cam_widget"
    android:configure="net.rex.camera.widget.CamWidgetConfig"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0">
</appwidget-provider>
```

CameraWidgetProvider:

```
public class CamWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private Context context;
    private DataBase dataBase;

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        this.context = context;
        dataBase = DataBase.getDataBaseInstance(context);
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout") RemoteViews widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.cam_widget);
        String name = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_NAME, "");
        if (name.equals("")) {
            for (int i : appWidgetIds) {
                // обновляем все экземпляры

                String nameWidg = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_NAME + "_" + i, "");
                String path = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_PATH + "_" + i, "");
                String img = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_IMG + "_" + i, "");
                String type = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE + "_" + i, "");
                String typeCapture = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE_CAPTURE + "_" + i, WidgetConstants.WIDGET_CAPTURE_PHOTO);
                widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.tvName, nameWidg);
                Intent intent = getPhotoIntent(path, nameWidg, type, i);
                setClickList(widgetView, intent, i);
                setClickConfig(widgetView, i);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(i, widgetView);
            }
        } else {
            int widgetId = appWidgetIds[0];
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            String path = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_PATH, "");
            String img = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_IMG, "");
            String type = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE, "");
            String typeCapture = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE_CAPTURE, WidgetConstants.WIDGET_CAPTURE_PHOTO);
            editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_NAME + "_" + widgetId, name);
            editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_PATH + "_" + widgetId, path);
            editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_IMG + "_" + widgetId, img);
            editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE + "_" + widgetId, type);
            editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE_CAPTURE + "_" + widgetId, typeCapture);
            editor.apply();
            resetDefPrefsValues(editor);
            widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.tvName, name);
            Intent intent = getPhotoIntent(path, name, type, widgetId);
            setClickList(widgetView, intent, widgetId);
            setClickConfig(widgetView, widgetId);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, widgetView);
        }

  
    }

    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
        // Удаляем Preferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(
                WidgetConstants.WIDGET_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        for (int widgetID : appWidgetIds) {
            editor.remove(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_NAME + "_" + widgetID);
            editor.remove(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_PATH + "_" + widgetID);
            editor.remove(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_IMG + "_" + widgetID);
            editor.remove(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE + "_" + widgetID);
            editor.remove(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE_CAPTURE + "_" + widgetID);
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void resetDefPrefsValues(SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_NAME, "");
        editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_PATH, "");
        editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_IMG, "");
        editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE, "");
        editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE_CAPTURE, "");
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void setClickList(RemoteViews widgetView, Intent intent, int widgetID) {
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, widgetID,
                intent, 0);
        widgetView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.pressView, pIntent);
    }

    public void setClickConfig(RemoteViews widgetView, int widgetID) {
        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, CamWidgetConfig.class);
        configIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE);
        configIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID);
        configIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, widgetID,
                configIntent, 0);
        widgetView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.prefsWidg, pIntent);
    }

    public Intent getPhotoIntent(String folderPath, String folderName, String type, int widgetID) {
        if (folderName.equals(MainActivity.DEFAULT_CAMERA_FOLDER)) {
            Intent intentMainCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
            return intentMainCamera;
            /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                createChooserPhoto();
            }*/
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CameraActivity.class); //заменить не забыть
            if (folderName.equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.folder_selfie))) {
                intent.putExtra("selfie", true);
            }
            if (type.equals("external")) {
                if (AppFileManager.getSdDocumentDcim() != null) {
                    intent.putExtra("type", "photo");
                    intent.putExtra("fileType", "Document");
                    intent.putExtra("folderPath", folderPath);
                }
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    intent.putExtra("type", "photo");
                    intent.putExtra("fileType", "Document");
                    intent.putExtra("folderPath", folderPath);
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("type", "photo");
                    intent.putExtra("fileType", "File");
                    intent.putExtra("folderPath", folderPath);
                }
            }
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            return intent;
        }
    }

    public Intent getVideoIntent(String folderPath, String folderName, String type, int widgetID) {
        if (folderName.equals(context.getString(R.string.folder_video))) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            return intent;
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CameraActivity.class);
            if (type.equals("external")) {
                intent.putExtra("fileType", "Document");
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    intent.putExtra("fileType", "Document");
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra("fileType", "File");
                }
            }
            intent.putExtra("type", "video");
            intent.putExtra("folderPath", folderPath);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            return intent;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (intent != null) {
//            String superP = intent.getStringExtra("super");
//            Log.i("i_tag", "superP=" + superP);
        }
    }
```

И CamWidgetConfig:

```
public class CamWidgetConfig extends AppCompatActivity {
    int widgetID = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    Intent resultValue;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    RadioButton photoRadio;
    RadioButton videoRadio;
    Spinner spnWidg;
    List<SimpleWidgFile> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // извлекаем ID конфигурируемого виджета
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            widgetID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }
        // и проверяем его корректность
        if (widgetID == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            finish();
        }

        // формируем intent ответа
        resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID);

        // отрицательный ответ
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, resultValue);
        //Видимо так положено ^

        setContentView(R.layout.widget_cam_config);

        sp = getSharedPreferences(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String typeCapture = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE_CAPTURE+"_"+widgetID, WidgetConstants.WIDGET_CAPTURE_PHOTO);
        String pathSpin = sp.getString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_PATH+"_"+widgetID, "");
        photoRadio = findViewById(R.id.photoRadio);
        videoRadio = findViewById(R.id.videoRadio);
        if(typeCapture.equals(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_CAPTURE_VIDEO)) {
            photoRadio.setChecked(false);
            videoRadio.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            photoRadio.setChecked(true);
            videoRadio.setChecked(false);
        }
        DataBase dataBase = DataBase.getDataBaseInstance(this);
        Cursor cursor = dataBase.getAllFolders();
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            SimpleWidgFile swf = new SimpleWidgFile();
            swf.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.COLUMN_FOLDER_NAME));
            swf.path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.COLUMN_FOLDER_PATH));
            swf.type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.COLUMN_STORAGE));
            list.add(swf);
        }
        cursor.close();
        int selectPos = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            SimpleWidgFile swf0 = list.get(i);
            if(swf0.path.equals(pathSpin)) {
                selectPos = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        MySpinnerAdapter mspAdapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(this,
                R.layout.spinner_widg_config, list);
        spnWidg = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnWidg);
        spnWidg.setAdapter(mspAdapter);
        spnWidg.setSelection(selectPos);
        Button clBtn = findViewById(R.id.clBtn);
        clBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               /* AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.cam_widget);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetID, views);
                Intent resultValue = new Intent().putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID);*/
                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
                finish();


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //super.onBackPressed();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        if(photoRadio.isChecked()) {
            editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE_CAPTURE+"_"+widgetID, WidgetConstants.WIDGET_CAPTURE_PHOTO);
        } else {
            editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE_CAPTURE+"_"+widgetID, WidgetConstants.WIDGET_CAPTURE_VIDEO);
        }
        SimpleWidgFile swf  = list.get(spnWidg.getSelectedItemPosition());
        editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_NAME + "_" + widgetID, swf.name);
        editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_PATH + "_" + widgetID, swf.path);
        editor.putString(WidgetConstants.WIDGET_KEY_TYPE + "_" + widgetID, swf.type);
        editor.apply();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
    }

    public class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SimpleWidgFile> {

        public MySpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<SimpleWidgFile> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent) {

            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }


        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
                                  ViewGroup parent) {
            SimpleWidgFile swf = getItem(position);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_widg_config, parent, false);
            }
            TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.path);
            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            label.setText(swf.path);
            name.setText(swf.name);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconPath);
            if(swf.type.equals("internal")) {
                //Glide.with(getContext()).load(userConfig.getPhotoUri()).into(userAvatar);
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.store_phone);
            } else {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_store);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public class SimpleWidgFile {
        public String path;
        public String type;
        public String name;
    }

}
```

Еще хочется заметить я там вызываю виджет в приложении с помощью `requestPinAppWidget` но я также пробовал по обычному виджет создавать из устройства, ставил Toast для сдлежения за классом провайдера, но тщетно, только класс конфигурации завершал работу, класс провайдера виджета не вызывался. Может что то я упускаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно послать широковещательное сообщение системе, что ваш виджет нужно обновить и самому же его ловить в методе наследника класса `AppWidgetProvider` `onUpdate`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE, null, this, AppWidgetProviderMy.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] {widgetID});
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Про `requestPinAppWidget` поделюсь своим опытом. Эта возможность появилась с Андроид 8 и лишь немногие launcher'ы поддерживали ее, а некоторые модели, например Xiaomi несмотря на возврат теста true ничего не делали. Далее была еще путаница с вызовом Intent'а конфигурирования. По документации программист сам с помощью слушателя должен был его запускать, так и было на некоторых устройствах, по факту некоторые модели запускали этот Intent самостоятельно, что приводило к вызову активности дважды: в начале установки виджета и в конце.

Comment: Спасибо. Правда я уже решил проблему тем что сделал вызовом статического метода, вот так CamWidgetProvider.updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, ids); Но ваш ответ тоже работает. Я не знаю какой более правильный но работают оба.

Comment: @Madoka Magica Правильный тот который гибче, то есть без статики.